# awk compare one column from two CSV files and display fields from both files

Tags: csv, awk

I want to compare second column of 1st file with 1st column of 2nd file, if match found display all fields from 1st file and all fields from 2nd file.

file1:

```
"971525408953","a8:5b:78:5a:dd:dc","TRUE"
"971558216784","ec:1f:72:24:7b:30","TRUE"
"971506509910","e8:50:8b:d8:f3:b5","TRUE"
"971509525934","c8:14:79:b4:bc:da","FALSE"
"971506904830","58:48:22:83:87:7f","TRUE"
```

file2:

```
"fc:e9:98:1e:a2:a2",2016-03-07 23:39:29,"TRUE"
"c8:14:79:b4:bc:da",2016-03-08 04:26:06,"TRUE"
"78:a3:e4:87:df:19",2015-12-30 01:22:42,"TRUE"
"18:f6:43:b1:82:47",2016-03-08 08:38:41,"TRUE"
"58:48:22:83:87:7f",2015-12-22 01:22:42,"TRUE"
```

output expected:

```
"c8:14:79:b4:bc:da",2016-03-08 04:26:06,"TRUE","971509525934","c8:14:79:b4:bc:da","FALSE"
"58:48:22:83:87:7f",2015-12-2201:22:42,"TRUE","971506904830","58:48:22:83:87:7f","TRUE"
```

But if i run following command i get this output without n[$2] and n[$3]

```
awk -F","  'NR==FNR { n[$2] = $1; next }  ($1 in n)  {print  $1,$2,$3,n[$1],n[$2],n[$3] }'  file1 file2 

"c8:14:79:b4:bc:da",2016-03-0804:26:06,"TRUE","971509525934",, "58:48:22:83:87:7f",2015-12-22 01:22:42,"TRUE","971506904830",,
```

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: I found what i wanted :)

awk -F","  -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR { n[$2] = $1$2$3; next }  ($1 in n)  {print  $1,$2,$3, n[$1] }' file1 file2

Answer (score 0):

awk -F","  -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR { n[$2] = $1$2$3; next }  ($1 in n)  {print  $1,$2,$3, n[$1] }' file1 file2

output:

"c8:14:79:b4:bc:da",2016-03-08 04:26:06,"TRUE","971509525934""c8:14:79:b4:bc:da""TRUE"
"58:48:22:83:87:7f",2015-12-22 01:22:42,"TRUE","971506904830""58:48:22:83:87:7f""TRUE"